# textchanged event trigger after given seconds

Tags: c#

My requirement is that, there is a textbox and a datagrid , when i enter text in textbox by scanning, if the value is present in database it should be added to datagrid and textbox value should go empty.
i have kept this functionality in textbox textchanged event.

```
  VALUE:
  16789
  35688
  1678934
  097544
```

if i scan'1678934', the value corresponding to '16789' is added in the grid and only 34 remains in textbox. how do i overcome this. should i place some timer so that once the scanning is complete the value may get added to the grid? how do i do it! or is there anyother event?

I used the following code

```
    private void txtValue_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            if (txtValue.Text != "")
            {
                dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
                strValue = "SELECT NAME FROM EMPDETAIL WHERE ID = @input";
                MySqlCommand cmdValue = new MySqlCommand(strValue, connection);
                connection.Open();
                cmdValue.Parameters.AddWithValue("@input", input);
                MySqlDataAdapter adapterValue = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmdValue);
                DataTable dtValue = new DataTable();
                adapterValue.Fill(dtValue);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dtValue;
                connection.Close();
            }
    }
```

EDIT:

Below Is the code to achieve the above functionality (as per @Daniel's Answer)

```
  private void textBox2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    { 
          if (txtValue.Text != "")
            {
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
                {
                dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
                strValue = "SELECT NAME FROM EMPDETAIL WHERE ID = @input";
                MySqlCommand cmdValue = new MySqlCommand(strValue, connection);
                connection.Open();
                cmdValue.Parameters.AddWithValue("@input", input);
                MySqlDataAdapter adapterValue = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmdValue);
                DataTable dtValue = new DataTable();
                adapterValue.Fill(dtValue);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dtValue;
                connection.Close();
                }
            }
         }
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you wouldn't get the user to press a button to confirm input (ie enter the text then press enter on the keyboard) then put the method on the KeyDown event.

Comment: @Daniel ,requirement says that when u scan the value it should directly fetch and add to the grid and no extra button is needed .. i tried the technique u said but user doesnot require extra button functionality

Comment: When you Scan? That isn't in the question, but also is belied by the fact that you are entering this clearly one character at a time. I am talking not about a button but a KeyDown event on the text box that checks if the user has pressed enter on their keyboard.

Comment: its a touch screen app @Daniel. No enter functionality. When user scans, the  value should get fetched and listed in grid

Comment: so there isn't any keyboard entering of information? What are you scanning, numbers or barcodes? How are you testing, by typing or scanning?

Comment: Information is entered by Scanning. @Daniel. And I am Scanning Product Barcode.(which in turn is numbers)

Comment: And yet when you are testing you are typing (as indicated in your question). Are you not scanning in testing? Is this a debug only issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is of course that if product "123" exists, it'll be found when scanning product "1234". You can work around this using a timer like you suggested, but you really don't want that.

Barcode scanners (usually, and configurably) add a character after scanning, for example a newline character (`\n`).

Instead of looking up the record in the TextChanged event, add a default button to the form (which will be clicked by this newline interpreted as Enter key press), or use the KeyPress event to find out when the termination character is entered.

Comment: Thank You. But i am struggling to check new line character after barcode scanning.

Comment: :) :) You are Genius :) I got it. I used keydown event :)